# Button won't load another screen?

Tags: android, eclipse, button, load, screen

I have just started using XML code, and I was trying to make a button that will take me to another screen, but for some reason the second screen won't open when I click the button. I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Here is the code I am using:

```
public class MyHomeScreen extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.Layout.main);
    setContentView(R.layout.homescreenlayout);


    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(MyHomeScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
        MyHomeScreen.this.startActivity(nextIntent);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        }
    }); 

}
```

I also get a warning saying "The method OnClick(View) from the type new View.OnClickListener(){} is never used locally"

Answer (score 1):

`public void OnClick(View v)` should be `public void onClick(View v)`. 
Don't forget to add the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: Then I get an error stating "Duplicate method onClick(View) in type new View.OnClickListener(){}"

Comment: @MiquelVilà Delete the second `onClick` function and move the `@Override` annotation to the first one.

Comment: Thanks. Where exactly should I move the @Override?

Comment: Just above the declaration of the `onClick` method.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
            Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YourClass.this);
                    startActivity(in);

                }
            });
```

Hope that helps

Comment: You don't need to have the onClick method twice.